# How to implement PayPal Adaptive payments to WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm writing extenstion for the WooCommerce plugin and I got one problem with multiple payments.
I want to use PayPal and I think the best way to do that is implement PayPal Adaptive payments. I've read PayPal's and WooCommerce's documentation but I can't figure it out.

I got defined new Payment Gateway, as documentations said:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-api/

```
class WC_Gateway_Adaptive_PayPal extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

public $environment = 'sandbox';

public function __construct() {

    $this->notify_url = str_replace( 'https:', 'http:', add_query_arg( 'wc-api', 'WC_Gateway_Adaptive_Paypal', home_url( '/' ) ) );

    $this->id = 'adaptive_paypal';
    $this->has_fields = false;
    $this->method_title = 'PayPal';
    $this->method_description = 'Handle payment with many receivers (up to 5)';

    $this->init_form_fields();
    $this->init_settings();

    $this->title = $this->get_option( 'title' );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_'.$this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );

}

public function init_form_fields() {

    $this->form_fields = array(
        'enabled' => array(
            'title' => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'wpgmpc' ),
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => __( 'Enable Adaptive PayPal Payment', 'wpgmpc' ),
            'default' => 'yes'
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'title' => __( 'Title', 'wpgmpc' ),
            'type' => 'text',
            'description' => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'wpgmpc' ),
            'default' => __( 'PayPal', 'wpgmpc' ),
            'desc_tip'      => true,
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'title' => __( 'Customer Message', 'wpgmpc' ),
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'default' => ''
        ),
        'percentage' => array(
            'title' => __( 'Fee', 'wpgmpc' ),
            'type' => 'number',
            'description' => __( 'Decide how much you want to take from each payment in %', 'wpgmpc' ),
            'desc_tip'      => true,
            'default' => '0'
        ),
        'receiver_email' => array(
            'title' => __( 'Receiver Email', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'          => 'email',
            'description' => __( 'If this differs from the email entered above, input your main receiver email for your PayPal account. This is used to validate IPN requests.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'default' => '',
            'desc_tip'      => true,
            'placeholder'   => 'you@youremail.com'
        ),
    );

}

public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

}

}
```

But according to default PayPal payment which is implemented in WooCommerce it's really messed up.

I know that:
 - I must call API for PayKey 
 - I must use cURL

I don't know how to redirect user to PayPal's payment page and even how to get this PayKey within WooCommerce Gateway API. I used some snippets I found on SO but they didn't work at all.

I will appreciate any help.
Thanks!

EDIT:
Right now I noticed that i can make redirection from WordPress to custom URL in process_payment method! But still I don't know how to implement IPN. When I receive PayKey I can just redirect to url with it?

Comment: have you got any solution for that problem?